# jQuery plugin to display "loading" while waiting for AJAX response

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have written some jQuery ajax code where I am sending a request to the server when a drop down option is changed.  Based on this change, 4 or 5 text fields change their data and bunch of new images get loaded. Everything feels nifty.

But I was wondering if there was a plugin provided by jQuery that would make the page dark...show 'loading' or spinner for a quick second until request comes back from the server?  I remember seeing one around but am not able to find it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's two objects you can pass to the generic ajax object called `ajaxStart` and `ajaxStop`. These are event handlers which fire whenever an ajax query is sent and received.

> **ajaxStart** (Global Event)
>   This event is broadcast if an Ajax request is started and no other Ajax requests are currently running.
>
> **ajaxStop** (Global Event)
>   This global event is triggered if there are no more Ajax requests being processed.

With that in mind, it's fairly easy to set up what you're after:

```
$("#loading").bind("ajaxStart", function(){
    $(this).show();
}).bind("ajaxStop", function(){
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Just make your `#loading` div whatever you like - take a look at the numerous lightbox plugins or [BlockUI](http://malsup.com/jquery/block/) to achieve something like what you asked.

Of course, you could set it to do whatever you like, but once that's set up at the top of your script, it's set-and-forget.

If you are using the BlockUI plugin, then all you have to do is this:

```
$().ajaxStart($.blockUI).ajaxStop($.unblockUI);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using jQuery Ajax event methods ajaxStart() and ajaxComplete()

[Documentation here under Ajax Events](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax)